# Suggested indices for a MPTT table

Tags: sql, database, tree, mptt

I'm just building a table to store hierarchical data using the Modified Pre-order Tree Traversal (MPTT) -- you know the one: each node stores the `left` and `right` IDs to find its descendants. I'm using a the CakePHP suggested model, which varies from the standard way by including the `parent_id` with each row.

Here's the suggested table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
    id INTEGER(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    parent_id INTEGER(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    lft INTEGER(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    rght INTEGER(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY  (id)
);
```

Having never used this style before, and not knowing exactly how it gets searched, I'm wondering which fields I should be indexing? Is just the primary key sufficient, or should I be including `lft` and `rght` too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i generally index just the left column. i usually work with mysql, which only allows for one index user per table in an execution plan, and an index on left helps every query i've ever written for a MPTT table and the benfits of including right in that index are minimal.

in short, a single index on left, in my experience, is the optimum balance between insert/update speed and select speed for nearly every use case.

Answer (score 4):

You will always be using the left column, however I often need to find all leaf nodes.

```
WHERE lft = (rgt -1)
```

So I usually just create a index with the pair lft, rgt.

Comment: This. Most trees are read a lot more than they are written to, so having a two-column index (not 2 separate indexes) on left and right is great.  
Also, if you're storing multiple trees in the same table, e.g. grouping by user, make it a three-column index on grouping_id, left, right.